# How do I correctly use Kotlin to call a blank fragment from the Home fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val fab = v.findViewById(R.id.fab) as FloatingActionButton
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val blankFragment = BlankFragment()
            val manager = childFragmentManager
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, blankFragment, blankFragment.tag).commit()

           // System.out.println("You have reached the floating action button")
        }
        return v
    }
}
```

Getting a no view found error. I may have issues with the R.id.frame_content but Kotlin doesn't immediately identify all id values...

Comment: What does "Kotlin doesn't immediately identify all id values..." mean? I doubt you have any issue with kotlin since it doesn't know about fragments and views. Something in your layout hierarchy is wrong. Where is the `R.id.frame_container `in relation to `R.layout.fragment_home`? The `childFragmentManager` cannot access the `frame_container`  if it's not inside the `fragment_home` layout. You'd need to use the activity's fragment manager for example if you want to replace a fragment up in the heirarchy

Comment: I can't do it but this question should be down voted. There were no error shown to help determine the exact cause of the problem. And code for the whole fragment should have been posted. It would also help if you posted the code for blank fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way and I apologize for the horrible formatting I does this while answer out on my phone and it's hard to get it perfect.  Anyways In the activity that holds your fragments, such as MainActivity.kt add...

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_home, HomeFragment.newInstance, "HomeFragment").commit()
```

In your HomeFragment.kt change the following.

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment(){
companion object { 
fun newInstance(): HomeFragment{
return HomeFragment() }

fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
val activity = activity 
return view
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { view ->
when (view.getId()) {
 R.id.fab -> NextFragment()
 }
 }
 fab.setOnClickListener(clickListener)
 }
 NextFragment(){
 val fragManager = activity?.supportFragmentManager
 fragManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.frame_container, BlankFragment.newInstance(), "blankFragment")?.commit()
}
```

Make sure you make the same changes to BlankFragment.kt

```
class BlankFragment: Fragment(){
companion object {
fun newInstance(): BlankFragment{
return BlankFragment() }
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
val activity = activity
return view
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
//Do some stuff with your views in BlankFragment here
}
}
```